# How to download file after form submit and 302 redirect using wget or curl

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to download a CSV file from the command line.  You input a stock ticket into the form field, click download, and the file is downloaded.  Here's the flow:

Site in question is [here](http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx).

The flow goes like this:

1. Browse to `http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx`
2. Enter ticker into form field and click download
3. Form action POSTs to `http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx`
4. Response is 302 with location header set to `http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteData.dat`
5. Browser follows redirect and GETs `http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteData.dat`
6. Browser downloads `QuoteData.dat` which is the CSV I want

Pics showing request/response:

[image: After POST]

[image: After redirect]

Chrome's RestClient shows the flow as well
[image: Restclient]

Wget follows the initial 302 to the QuoteData.dat URL, but doesn't download that file before redirecting again.

[image: wget result]

I've copied the headers and cookies to use with wget and curl with no success.  I've 'Copied as Curl' from the Chrome Inspector with no success.  I've played around with casperjs as well, but I've gotten further with curl and wget.

I'm mildly obsessed with figuring this out now :)  Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Here is the wget command I'm using:

```
wget --post-file=cboe_form_data.txt -L http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx
```

`cboe_form_data.txt` is the post data taken from the chrome inspector: `http://sandalsoft.com/cboe_form_data.txt`

Comment: Save the result from the redirect to a file somewhere then call curl -0 on that file? That is of course assuming that the redirect if giving you the path to the file. If it's not, if it's doing the file along side the redirect then you'll need to grab it from the headers before calling the curl. Either way I'd try taw joint this as a 2 step problem. 1) get the file path 2) download it.

Comment: I've tried something like that.  I've run the wget command above followed by a wget to the redirect location http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteData.dat.  It doesn't download the file, just the .asp page.  Wget doesn't save the redirected file, it follows the 302, then the subsequent 302.  No .CSV is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site seems to require the `Referer` header:

```
wget --post-file=cboe_form_data.txt \
--header='Referer: http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx' \
http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx
```

With this command the "QuoteData.dat" `GET` request will feature the `Referer` header. Response code for that request is `200` and the CSV is included.

When the `Referer` header isn't present the "QuoteData.dat" `GET` request returns code `302` and an "Object moved" HTML page. In that case client is sent back to "QuoteTableDownload.aspx".

Comment: That was it, I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `wget ....../QuotrTableDownload.aspx`, it's download this aspx file,for the ...../Quitedata.dat ,wget treats them as foreign (they are not in ..../QuoteTableDownload.aspx), so you need the --span-hosts switch. Going to ...../QuoteData.dat , this option might help.:)

Comment: I tried using these commands and it didn't work: `wget --post-file=cboe_form_data.txt -L http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx -v --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt --span-hosts --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0"` and  `wget --post-file=cboe_form_data.txt -L http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx -v --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt --span-hosts --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0"; wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0" http://www.cboe.com//DelayedQuote/QuoteData.dat --span-hosts` I'm using from form data (i think)